# Twitch OAuth access_token instead of Bearer token

Tags: api, twitch, twitch-api

Twitch has New API and V5 API, and I want to use exactly the V5 API since that's API gives a little bit more info about channel. And when I'm use assess_token from browser dev tools, API is working.

[image]

But when I'm using assess_token got by Omniauth authorization, API is not working and errors like `{"error":"Gone","status":410,"message":"It's time to kick ass and serve v3... and I'm all outta v3. See https://dev.twitch.tv/docs"}` are constantly appeared. The docs said the V5 API is still working (though deprecated).

[image]

Helix and Kraken APIs has different types of tokens (`Bearer` and `OAuth`)

[image]

How can I get exactly the `OAuth` access_token to be able to work with V5 API after user authentication?
Token from browser dev tools is working as with the New API and with the V5 API but token got from Omniauth is working only with New API.

**SOLVED**

Access token might be used for both New API and V5 API. For using V5 API just need to add `Accept` header with `application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json` into request.

Comment: The v5 API has now been properly deprecated by Twitch. You have to use the new endpoint: `https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/` as outlined in the updated doco: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication.